# Mongoose date comparison

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My application will allow user to create coupons.

Coupon will be valid in `datefrom` and `dateto` period.

The thing is that every coupon should be valid for selected days, not hours.

For example since Monday(2016-06-12) to Tuesday(2016-06-13), so two days.

How should I store dates on server side and then compare it using `$gte` clause in Mongoose?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

```
{ "_id" : 1, "couponStartDate" : ISODate("2016-06-26T18:57:30.012Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "couponStartDate" : ISODate("2016-06-26T18:57:35.012Z") }


var startDate = new Date(); // I am assuming this is gonna be provided 
var validDate = startDate;
var parametricDayCount = 2;
validDate.setDate(validDate.getDate()+parametricDayCount);
CouponModel.find({couponStartDate: {$gte: startDate, $lte: validDate}}, function (err, docs) { ... });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store expiration time as UNIX timestamp. In your Mongoose model you can use `expiration : { type: Number, required: true}`

If you have user interface for creating coupons then you can configure your date picker to send time in UNIX timestamp.

Or If you are getting Date string then you can use `var timestamp = new Date('Your_Date_String');`

And for calculation of Days you can use [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/). Using this you can calculate start of the date using `.startOf();` and end of date using `.endOf();`

Timestamp return from Moment JS can be used for Mongoose query like `$gte : some_timestamp` and `$lte : some_timestamp`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `validate` the coupon before it is persisted, you can create a `max / min` value for the date field:

See this sample from official [mongoose documentation on DATE validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-date-js):

```
var s = new Schema({ dateto: { type: Date, max: Date('2014-01-01') })
var M = db.model('M', s)
var m = new M({ dateto: Date('2014-12-08') })
m.save(function (err) {
  console.error(err) // validator error
  m.dateto = Date('2013-12-31');
  m.save() // success
})
```

Hint: use `snake_case` or `camelCase` for field names