# Node.js with Mongoose database find issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been having an very odd issue and I think it might be the way I am doing nested levels in the mongoose schema.  First lets get the schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RLSchema = new Schema({
    user_id: { type: String, required: true },
    coordinate: {
        accuracy: Number,
        latitude: Number,
        longitude: Number
    },
    agency_id: String,
    received_time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    department_id: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('RL', RLSchema);
```

And I am creating a dynamic search with this since I dont know what they are going to search with.  All I know is if you are searching based on received_time you need to send in the To and From:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var regexp = require('node-regexp');

var RL = require('./app/models/rl');

var uristring = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/mydev';

mongoose.connect(uristring, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

app.get('/api/rl', function(req, res) {
    var findQuery = "{";
    var qry = "";

    if (req.query.agency_id) {
        findQuery = findQuery + " agency_id: \"" + req.query.agency_id + "\",";
    }

    if (req.query.department_id) {
        findQuery = findQuery + " \"department_id\": \"" + req.query.department_id + "\",";
    }

    if (req.query.user_id) {
        findQuery = findQuery + " \"user_id\": \"" + req.query.user_id + "\",";
    }

    var isOne = ((req.query.from) || (req.query.to));
    var isBoth = ((req.query.from) && (req.query.to));

    if (isOne) {
        if (isBoth) {
            findQuery = findQuery + " \"received_time\": { \"$lte\": " + req.query.to + ", \"$gte\": " + req.query.from + "},"
        } else {
            res.status(400).json("{ message: 'Missing the to or from time for searching}'");
            return res;
        }
    }

    qry = findQuery.substring(0, findQuery.length - 1);
    qry = qry + "}";
    if (qry.length < 2) {
        qry = "{}";
    }

    if (!isBoth) {
        qry = "";
    }

    RL.find(JSON.parse(qry)).toArray(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get information");
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(doc);
        }
    });
});
```

Everytime I call this I get back:
Error
Internal Server Error

even if I remove all the code and just send in what is below I still get the Internal Server Error.  Do you know why this would not work?

```
ResponderLocation.Find({ agency_id: req.query.agency_id }).toArray(function(err, rl){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(rl);
    });
```

Comment: 1. Don't build json string and then parse it to object, just build the object. 2. `Find` should be lowercased to `find`. 3. You might want to `console.log(err)` to read the error.

Comment: thanks for the comment.  Here is what I am seeing now:
1.  Not sure how the object should look.  When I tried it I got that the object could not be read in the console log.
2. Fixed the find to lowercase in the simple search still did not work.  Console Log now said that we can not use toArray so I removed that and change it to this and it worked (sent me everything):ResponderLocation.find(function(err, rl){

So I guess I am down to how to dynamically creating the query

Comment: `var query = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', ...};` then `if(condition){query[key] = something}` finally, `ResponderLocation.find(query)...`.

Comment: Normally, when you get a 500 error, you should be shown an error in your logs. I know for one thing [`.find().toArray()` does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858299/model-find-toarray-claiming-to-not-have-toarray-method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As q4w56 pointed out, you should build an object opposed to a string and there is no function `Find`.

Here's how I would refactor your code:

```
app.get('/api/rl', function(req, res) {
    var query = {};
    if (req.query.agency_id) {
        query.agency_id = req.query.agency_id;
    }
    if (req.query.department_id) {
        query.department_id = req.query.department_id;
    }
    if (req.query.user_id) {
        query.user_id = req.query.user_id;
    }
    if (!req.query.from && !req.query.to) {
        // .json() expects a JSON not a string as argument
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Missing the to or from time for searching' });
    }
    query.received_time = {};
    if (req.query.from) {
        query.received_time.$gte = req.query.from;
    }
    if (req.query.to) {
        query.received_time.$lte = req.query.to;
    }
    // no need for toArray()
    ResponderLocation.find(query, function(err, locations) {
        if (err) {
            handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get information");
        } else {
            // no need to send 200 status as that is default
            res.json(locations); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am going to try your refactoring.  I just now got it working using strings like because I was missing the \" in front of agency_id and after it.  The JSON parser could not read agency_id as a string and was throwing an error.

Comment: Yep that worked except for the to and from.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Double-check the format of `req.query.from` and `req.query.to` and the `Date` format that is saved in the collection. I think `req.query.from` and `req.query.to` need to be converted into `Date` objects as shown in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37572488/1022914).